# UIApplication delegate method is not called

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, delegates

I have a problem integrating Facebook SDK 3.2 with my app, my app goes to facebook app for approval and login, but when

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation;
```

needs to be called when facebook authorization is done, it simply skips it. 
It works great when I force webView facebook login via modal viewcontroller, but when I want to use installed facebook app/safari it just doesn't work.
Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: how you are opening facbook login page in safari

Comment: put breat point in applicationDidBecomeActive, is that called ?

Comment: Try keeping breakpoint on this method to check if its getting called

Comment: @Guru
When returning back to my app from the facebook app login, applicationDidBecomeActive isn't called.

Comment: then its not your app delegate class..or you missed UIApplicationDelegate in interface declaration.

Comment: How about "Finally, you need to place the Facebook app ID in two places in your application's main .plist file. Create a key called FacebookAppID with a string value, and add the app ID there:"

Comment: @interface TestAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
and everything is set in plist.. Like I said it works when I login with modal webview controller, but it doesn't work when I use facebook app login/safari. Because I don't get the back information through the method which is not triggered (application openUrl...)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put UIApplicationDelegate in interface declaration.

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
```

Also verify its right App delegate class

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Also add fb Id in plist.
[image]

Comment: This all is set, and everything works when i open it through webview and force it like modal view controller. This is the code
`        [appDelegate.sessionFacebook openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                                                                               FBSessionState status,
                                                                                                               NSError *error){
            [self readFacebookData];
            
        }];`

Comment: And the code that doesn't work         [appDelegate.sessionFacebook openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState status,
                                                         NSError *error) {
            // we recurse here, in order to update buttons and labels
            [self readFacebookData];
        }];